# number of swipes per hour

Tags: swift, time

I am making an app that tallies the number of shakes, swipe ups and swipe rights per hour, per day, per month, per year and presenting them in a graph. I find it hard to code how many gestures are done in an hour. Please help me.

Here's my code for Shakes:

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.motionShake {
            if (Action1.text == "Shake"){
               shakeCountedNumber += 1
               shakeCounterLabel.text = String(shakeCountedNumber)
            }

        }

        if (timeAndDateLabel.text == "9:00 AM - 11:00 AM"){
            let shakes = shakeCountedNumber
            let shakeNineToTen = (timeAndDateLabel.text == "9:00 AM - 11:00 AM")
            print(shakes,shakeNineToTen)
        }
}
```

please help me. I am new in coding. Thank you!